# Set localstorage for a function which caches color values

Tags: javascript, local-storage, color-picker

I need to cache the the hex value/color of each input which is set by calling a function.

I have tried caching each color by rewriting duplicate functions for caching on-load, but was wondering if it could be done using a single function.

```
  function boardNames(color){
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('topname').length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('topname')[i].style.color = color
        }
  }
function leaderboardMass(color){
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('topmass').length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('topmass')[i].style.color = color
    }
 }

     $('.demo').minicolors({
        change: function(value) {
          if(this.id === 'bn-theme-e'){boardNames(value)}
          if(this.id === 'lm-theme-e'){leaderboardMass(value)}

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store a stringified object inside of `localStorage`. This way you can use and index multiple different colors. In my example, I use the element class names to store index the color values.

```
// Color all items that have been set
boardNames = () => {
  let colors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nc'));
  if (colors) {
    Object.entries(colors).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(k)).forEach(c => {
        c.style.color = v;
      });
    });
  }
  localStorage.setItem('nc', JSON.stringify(colors));
}

// Set the className with new color value
setBoardColor = (className, color) => {
  let colors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nc'));
  colors[className] = color;
  localStorage.setItem('nc', JSON.stringify(colors));
}
```

Comment: i have multiple id's in the demo class which call different functions like above, would i have to duplicate these 2 functions for each of the others?